# Bootstrap 3 - Equal Size Image Gallery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I display images in my web application using bootstrap grid.
Like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/d0/24/ae/d024aec06c754dbc440d6cf84e544704.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I want the images to be displayed on equal size without distorting the portrait images. What I'm thinking is putting the image in another div and automatically crop the images to 300px x 300px size-div. by cropping I mean hiding the part of the image that cannot be fitted equally in the 300 x 300 div. How can I do this? https://jsfiddle.net/Lb92rv84/4/

You can see that the image in the middle is too big. I want it to adapt automatically or all of them be 300px x 300px. I want it to be like a preview image only and when clicked just have a pop up of the real size image. (which i can do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the col-xs-4 div a fixed height, then use jQuery to set the current img tag to the col-xs-4 background-image css property, like this.

```
$(".img-to-bg").each(function(){
var img = $(this).find("img");
  $(this).css({
    "background-image": "url('"+img.prop("src")+"')",
    "background-size": cover,
    //Any other CSS background propriety
    //If your want the div to be square (same width and height)
    height: $(this).height()
  });
  img.remove();
});
```

User the img-to-bg class for the col-xs-4 divs

Answer (score 1):

Give some class to the **img tag** and set their width and height to whatever ratio you want. It will fix the image size and responsiveness OF THE IMAGE WILL ALSO BE MAINTAINED.

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block size" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/d0/24/ae/d024aec06c754dbc440d6cf84e544704.jpg">
```

CSS-

```
.size{
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
```

You can also give **center-block** class to the image tag as you can see in my img tag. It will algin the image at center of it's parent.